# Updating R, I do not understand the logic of how R works after updating R to latest version

Tags: r, updates

I've come across a common problem but do not understand the logic of how R works.

So I had R 3.4 and all my libraries were in /usr/local/.../R/3.4 local direction.  These libraries were installed using super user admin rights.

I've recently upgraded to R 4.0.0.2, and installed Rstudio, and do not run Rstudio as super user.  I've created a new local direction ~/R/x86_ubuntu/4.0 local library.

Now the `.libPaths()`  has the first entry as my local directory, and subsequent paths point to previous library paths.

So if i enter `install.packages(foo)`, the error says,

> This package package ‘foo’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it.Error: package ‘dotCall64’ could not be loaded.'

However I am re-installing the package from source, yet I get the error that I could not re-install it.

I have also tried the `install.updates(check=TRUE,ask=FALSE)` command and this still gave the same answer.

There are similar posts to this problem, but I just need an explanation as to why this is failing?

Is it because of the library paths conflict? R is trying to load a previous older 3.4 library directory?

This does not make sense because I've downloaded all my 4.0 libraries from source? why is it still pulling from the older versions?

Should I just remove other library paths?  Should I delete my old previous library folders?

Comment: After updating you need to update the packages too. Try 'update.packages()'

Comment: does it matter which directory I am updating from?  should I first update /usr/local/R/lib/site-library ?  I have several library paths in .libPaths(),  of them 1 is a local non-admin pathway, and the others are admin.  Do I need to update the admin directories first before the local library directory?

Comment: The files have to be compiled under the version of R that you are running. If you open the R 4.0.0.2 console you should be able to update from there.

Comment: You say the libpaths has the previous folders still? Like the packages that were installed with R3.4? Packages aren’t meant to be shared across minor versions. R will install new packages at the first folder in your libpaths but if that package has dependencies, it will look for them in all folders of the libpaths. Having 3.4 packages in a 4.0 libpath will certainly cause a problem.

Comment: I have to re-install each package one-by-one?  I am getting errors "package X was previously installed on an older version, please re-install it".  If I do install.packages() it grabs the source file but does not succeed because it installs packages linearly. thoughts